# mysql anomalies (ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file)

Tags: mysql

Something really weird happened to my MySQL database. This morning I came to work, and discovered that my Mac desktop was off, even though I left it on last night.

I started it up, and tried to log into my local MySQL DB (running on OS X 10.9.5) with my regular credentials, and got an Access Denied error. I tried to reset the root password via the terminal:

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
mysql -u root
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('password') WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Then I tried to restart the server:

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

And got

```
.. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/Mac-Pro.local.pid).
```

I tried to check if mysql process was running by typing `ps aux | grep mysql`, but got no results. I then decided to reboot, and after the reboot the server was running. However, if I tried to restart the server by typing `sudo mysql.server restart`, I'd get the same error:

```
 ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!
Starting MySQL
.. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/Mac-Pro.local.pid).
```

And `ps aux | grep mysql` now returns this:

```
_mysql            515   0.0  1.4  3141512 460288   ??  S    11:42AM   0:00.52 /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --plugin-dir=/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/usr/local/mysql/data/Mac-Pro.local.err --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/Mac-Pro.local.pid
root              282   0.0  0.0  2458968   1152   ??  S    11:42AM   0:00.02 /bin/sh /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/Mac-Pro.local.pid
verse  1392   0.0  0.0  2432784    644 s000  S+   11:47AM   0:00.00 grep mysql
```

I can connect to mysql via MySql Workbench, or the terminal, so the server is definitely running. However, I've discovered that the database is wiped out -- it completely disappeared!! I have restored the backup, but the problem with restart persists, and I'm worried that the data may disappear again. Any ideas on what could be causing these problems?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo move /etc/my.cnf /etc/my.cnf.bak
```

This worked for my to let mysql.server create fresh my.cnf file